# RODBC error handling for sqlQuery

Tags: sql, r, error-handling, odbc

I did not find any good error testing function for the results of an `sqlQuery` and that surprises me.

In the documentation (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/rodbc/docs/sqlQuery), they state that its return values are:

"On success, a data frame (possibly with 0 rows) or character string. On error, if errors = TRUE a character vector of error message(s), otherwise an invisible integer error code -1 (general, call odbcGetErrMsg for details) or -2 (no data, which may not be an error as some SQL statements do return no data)."

I never ever could replicate a -1 or a -2 being returned (with errors = false, by default). How is it possible?

If write a SELECT request with an invalid table, I get a string with the error message from SQL Server, but no -1L nor -2L. When do they occur?

In the same spirit, testing for SQL errors or empty result sets includes a cascade of smaller tests to avoid errors when testing.

I finally used the following if..else..else code, but I wonder if it's possible to simplify it (and why I never see -1 nor -2). That leaves me a bad feeling of not covering all the cases...

```
sql.invalid.table.name <-
 "SELECT pfiID
  FROM test"

sql.0.rows <-
 "SELECT pfiID
  FROM dossier
  WHERE pfiID = 'fake-id'"

sql.10.rows <-
 "SELECT pfiID
  FROM dossier
  WHERE pfiID like '%/200201/0001'"

records <- sqlQuery(channel, sql.invalid.table.name)

if (is.null(nrow(records))) {
  stop(paste("", records, sep="\n"))
} else if (nrow(records) == 0) {
  cat("No data\n")
} else
  print(head(records))

records <- sqlQuery(channel, sql.0.rows)

if (is.null(nrow(records))) {
  stop(paste("", records, sep="\n"))
} else if (nrow(records) == 0) {
  cat("No data\n")
} else
  print(head(records))

records <- sqlQuery(channel, sql.10.rows)

if (is.null(nrow(records))) {
  stop(paste("", records, sep="\n"))
} else if (nrow(records) == 0) {
  cat("No data\n")
} else
  print(head(records))
```

Any ideas/comments?

Comment: I don't know the details, but my hunch is that not all outcomes will be possible on all db's. So it may be that an ODBC connection with SQL Server will never return a -2, but MySQL might (for instance).

Comment: @joran -- Yes, you may be right!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the situation seems horrendous, but in practise it isn't as bad as it might be.  The documentation is vague and convoluted because `RODBC` handles connections to any sort of database and different databases return different things in the event of problems.

I've done a fair amount of work using ROBDC to connect R to SQL Server, and in general `SELECT` queries were easy enough to deal with: they return a data frame is they work, and a character vector if not.  So code like

```
records <- sqlQuery(channel, "SELECT blah FROM somewhere")
if(is.character(records))
{
  stop(paste(records, collapse = "\n"))
}
```

works well enough.

For absolute certainty, you'll need to be more thorough, but if you are connecting to only one type of database, it will hopefully be consistent about how it fails.

Comment: That's the same spirit as what I wrote, but simpler (`is.character` instead of `is.null(nrow)`). Thanks a lot for your answer!

Comment: As you do have expertise connecting to SQL Server, does it make sense to go and look for DBI?  Why well/not?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand the question.  If you meant "is there an R package for connecting to SQL Server that is based on the `DBI` package?", then the answer is yes.  See https://github.com/agstudy/rsqlserver

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. My question was: now that it seems that there is a convergence movement around DBI (IIUC), would it be a wise move to look at DBI instead of writing programs on top of RODBC?

Comment: The `rsqlserver` package is part of that convergence movement.  It is less mature than `RODBC` but it's still high quality.

Comment: May I ask one last question?  I don't find how to test that an UPDATE statement sent in a `sqlQuery` has been correctly executed. Is there a way to retrieve the number of modified rows?

Comment: Sorry I can't remember off the top of my head, and my new employer uses PostgreSQL rather than SQL Server, so I can't easily check. What gets returned when you `sqlQuery(channel, "UPDATE blah")`?

Comment: It returns a `character(0)`.

Comment: Does `verbose = TRUE` show you anything useful?  Combine that with `capture.output` if it does.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Sorry, though; I don't understand where to put the `verbose` argument. In `sqlQuery`, it is reported as being unused...

Comment: Discussion moved to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25762371/r-getting-the-number-of-rows-which-have-been-updated