# R Getting the number of rows which have been updated

Tags: sql, r, odbc, rodbc

How can we get the **number of rows** affected by the executed UPDATE query?

```
r <- sqlQuery(channel, 'UPDATE foo SET bar = 1')
```

What I get (from a connection to a MS SQL Server DB) is just a `character(0)`...

Comment: Discussion began in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727473/rodbc-error-handling-for-sqlquery

Answer (score 0):

From the Microsoft Data Access SDK ODBC Help guide:

SQLRowCount returns the number of rows affected by an UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statement; an SQL_ADD, SQL_UPDATE_BY_BOOKMARK, or SQL_DELETE_BY_BOOKMARK operation in SQLBulkOperations; or an SQL_UPDATE or SQL_DELETE operation in SQLSetPos.

I expect that there is a way to invoke this ODBC function via the api you are using.